# Firebase - Cloud Firestore Trigger Idempotency

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

The Firebase docs for Cloud Firestore Triggers mentions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#limitations_and_guarantees) that functions triggered by an event from the Firestore database should be idempotent.

Is there some kind of *event id* that is passed to the Cloud Function triggered by the Firestore event that could be used to identify whether or not a function is being executed more than once from the same Firestore event (and thus subsequent calls to the function with the same *event id* could be ignored)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each event in Cloud Functions comes with a context. Besides the commonly used `params` and `auth` objects it also comes with a [eventId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.eventcontext.md#eventcontexteventid) property which is a unique identifier for the event. (the link goes to the API docs for EventContext).

Comment: If for some reason Firebase triggers my Cloud Function more than once for the same database modification, will the `eventId` remain the same?

Comment: That's the theory.  I've never had to deal with it in practice, though, because not all functions that require idempotency also require a unique id to check.

Comment: The link is broken. Remember to always paste the solution.

Comment: @drdrdrdr The API docs just say what's being said here - it's a unique id.  The API changed with 1.0, which is why the link was broken.  It's fixed now.