# firestore cloud functions onCreate/onDelete sometimes immediately triggered twice

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have observed this behavior occasionally with both onCreate and onDelete triggers. 
[image]

Both the executions happened for the same document created in firestore. There's only one document there so I don't understand how it could trigger the handler twice. the handler itself is very simple:

```
module.exports = functions.firestore.document('notes/{noteId}').onCreate((event) => {
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const params = event.params;
  const data = event.data.data();
  // empty
});
```

this doesn't happen all the time. What am I missing?

Comment: what is there inside noteId?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Unfortunately, I did not log the params for this particular call. I have added the logs now and will update the questions if this happens again. When it happens for onDelete though, I have actually verified that it triggers onDelete for the same document id twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the Cloud Firestore Triggers [Limitations and Guarantees](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#limitations_and_guarantees):

> Delivery of function invocations is not currently guaranteed. As the
>   Cloud Firestore and Cloud Functions integration improves, we plan to
>   guarantee "at least once" delivery. However, this may not always be
>   the case during beta. **This may also result in multiple invocations
>   for a single event**, so for the highest quality functions ensure that
>   the functions are written to be idempotent.

There is a [Firecast video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pwsy8XR7HNE) with tips for implementing idempotence.

Also two Google Blog posts: [the first](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions), [the second](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-retries-and-idempotency-in-action).

Comment: Wow, thank you for your response. I can't believe I missed this while reading the docs. Will work on making the functions idempotent.

Comment: You can use the `eventId` that firebase passes to your function to help with indepotency as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972550/firebase-cloud-firestore-trigger-idempotency).

Comment: Does it fixed in Version 1.0.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions ?

Comment: @saranpol: I think this issue still exists with version 1.0.0.

Comment: OK, thank you @BobSnyder I think I will use EventContext.eventId and transaction to fix this issue

Comment: Am I the only one to find the behaviour completely outrageous ? Does it mean that I need to implement an eventID system on each of my functions that I don't want to be randomly ran twice ? How can Google even expect us to use Firebase in production with such a weird behaviour ? Such a bummer, seriously.

Comment: @schankam you're completely right, I'm using firebase as a backend for an inventory tracking system and so can't afford to have the function run multiple times and fuck up the inventory levels. It's just unacceptable

Comment: @fuadj After using Cloud Functions for a while now, I have to say that I find my own comment invalid right now. When using Cloud Functions, we just have to keep in mind that functions have to be idempotent, and then build our architecture accordingly. I wasn't really aware of this back then, but if you know it upfront then it's always possible to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @saranpol's answer we use the below for now. We have yet to check if we actually get any duplicate event ids though.

```
const alreadyTriggered = eventId => {
  // Firestore doesn't support forward slash in ids and the eventId often has it
  const validEventId = eventId.replace('/', '')

  const firestore = firebase.firestore()
  return firestore.runTransaction(async transaction => {
    const ref = firestore.doc(`eventIds/${validEventId}`)
    const doc = await transaction.get(ref)
    if (doc.exists) {
      console.error(`Already triggered function for event: ${validEventId}`)
      return true
    } else {
      transaction.set(ref, {})
      return false
    }
  })
}

// Usage
if (await alreadyTriggered(context.eventId)) {
  return
}
```

Comment: The transaction seems like a smart addition to this idea.  Maybe depending on how many events you process, it would be good to add a timestamp and clean stuff up older than X days?

Comment: By replacing the "/' character, won't this introduce possible collisions with other events ids?

Comment: Since I assume the IDs are randomly generated I think that is highly unlikely

Answer (score 1):

In my case I try to use **eventId** and **transaction** to prevent onCreate sometimes triggered twice

(you may need to save eventId in list and check if it exist if your function actually triggered often)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const db = admin.firestore()
exports = module.exports = functions.firestore.document('...').onCreate((snap, context) => {

  const prize = 1000
  const eventId = context.eventId
  if (!eventId) {
    return false
  }

  // increment money
  const p1 = () => {
    const ref = db.doc('...')
    return db.runTransaction(t => {
        return t.get(ref).then(doc => {
          let money_total = 0
          if (doc.exists) {
            const eventIdLast = doc.data().event_id_last
            if (eventIdLast === eventId) {
              throw 'duplicated event'
            }
            const m0 = doc.data().money_total
            if(m0 !== undefined) {
              money_total = m0 + prize
            }
          } else {
            money_total = prize
          }
          return t.set(ref, { 
            money_total: money_total,
            event_id_last: eventId
          }, {merge: true})
        })
    })
  }

  // will execute p2 p3 p4 if p1 success
  const p2 = () => {
    ...
  }

  const p3 = () => {
    ...
  }

  const p4 = () => {
    ...
  }

  return p1().then(() => {
    return Promise.all([p2(), p3(), p4()])
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, I had this issue but having a min instance solved the issue for me
Upon looking @xaxsis attached screenshot, my function took almost the amount of time about 15 seconds for the first request and about 1/4 of that for the second request