# Should firestore triggers be idempotent when there is no retry?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

It is not clear whether firestore triggers need to be idempotent, at least if they should be in all cases.

The doc mentions that the function needs to be idempotent in case of error retries which are opt in. In case someone did not opt-in, it is unclear whether a function needs to be idempotent.

I'm aware of the other post posted in comments, but they are at odds with firebase doc. Specifically:

> Your functions should produce the same result even if they are called multiple times. This lets you retry an invocation if the previous invocation fails partway through your code. For more information, see retrying event-driven functions.

That retry feature is an opt-in feature, therefor if you did not opt-in, does the function need to be idempotent ? Put it another way, if you did not opt-in for retries, can a function receive the same  event twice

**This piece of information is vital as idempotency can complexify some use cases**. So you wouldn't want to take it into account if it does not have to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase - Cloud Firestore Trigger Idempotency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972550/firebase-cloud-firestore-trigger-idempotency)

Comment: "Events are delivered at least once, but a single event may result in multiple function invocations. Avoid depending on exactly-once mechanics, and write idempotent functions." https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd#limitations

Comment: @Riwen not really, my question is different.

Comment: Does this help for you : [Building idempotent functions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if you did not opt-in for retries, can a function receive the same event twice

Yes, it can. You have to assume that the communication channel between the Cloud Functions event producers and your function code is asynchronous and is not 100% reliable (as computer systems often are).  There is no guarantee that an event that is meant for your function will actually end up in your function.  If an event is lost (because your function didn't receive it and acknowledge its receipt somehow), the event will be sent again, repeatedly, until your function runs and reports back to the event producer that the event was handled (or some max number of retries is exceeded).

These types of retries are different than the ones you opt into when your function explicitly fails on the processing of an event. A failure is a form of acknowledgement of the event. When you opt into retries for failure, that's for failures in your function code, not the system in general.

Whether or not **your** function **needs** to implement idempotency is entirely up to you, though.  Maybe it's not a big problem for you if the event gets processed twice, but we can't tell you if that's the case.  You have to define that requirement for your project.

Comment: I just watched a video on youtube by a firebaser named Doug that answered that question, probably You ! To be a bit more precise, does the event producer operates on a timeout before resending the event ? This seems like a very edge case

Comment: I can't tell you all the circumstances where an event and its ack can be dropped.  You just have to expect that it can happen rarely.